# Use string as parameter in a function

Tags: django

I'm trying to use a string as a parameter in a function. Is something like this possible?

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

param_var = 'contains'
User.objects.filter(first_name__{param_var}='John')

# ideally, this should equate to:
User.objects.filter(first_name__contains='John')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
param_var = 'contains'
User.objects.filter(**{'first_name__%s'%param_var: 'John'})
```

Though I really wonder about the wisdom of doing that... I think you may be re-inventing sql injection...

I suspect there's a better way.  You should probably explain more of what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @akonsu: Agreed.  Take this answer as: "Here's one way to slit your wrist, but are you really sure you want to?".

Answer (score 1):

**Solved:**

```
# Something like this...
qs = User.objects.all()

parameters = {
    'name': {
        'type': 'get',
        'filter': [
            'first_name__icontains',
            'last_name__icontains',
            # ...
        ],
    },
    # ...
}

for parameter, data in parameters.items():
    if data['type'] == 'get':
        value = request.GET.get(parameter, None)
    elif data['type'] == 'getlist':
        value = request.GET.getlist(parameter)

    if value:
        query = Q()

        for f in data['filter']:
            query = query | Q(**{ f : value })
        qs = qs.filter(query)
```